# Filling the empty space in RevolutionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, filling

I'm wanting to plot the solid of revolution from the area between two functions such as: $1\leq x \leq e$ and $1 \leq y \leq 2 + ln(x)$, doing something like this:

```
f[x_]:=2+Log[x]
g[x_]:=1
RevolutionPlot3D[{{f[x]}, {g[x]}}, {x, 1, E},
 RevolutionAxis -> x, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 Boxed -> False, Mesh -> {5, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, All},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
```

[image: plot]

Is there a way to fill this empty space between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one doesn't need V10:

```
RegionPlot3D[ 1 < Sqrt[z z + y y] < 2 + Log[x], {x, 1, E}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
              Mesh -> None, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this is much nicer graphic...and a much nicer inequality (which I should have exploited...+1 obviously

Comment: Very elegant code and result, Thank you!

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks. The "nicer" part really depends on the plot range. Try using `{x, 1/2, E}` instead of `{x, 1, E}` and see by yourself.

Answer (score 4):

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[
  g[x]^2 <= y^2 + z^2 <= f[x]^2 && 1 < x < E, {x, y, z}];
RegionPlot3D[ir, PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image]

or

```
DiscretizeRegion[ir]
```

[image]