# Solid of revolution

Tags: plotting

How can I visualize the volume of the solid of revolution generated by the functions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ in mathematica? I asked chat-gpt and it gave me the command

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
  RevolutionAxis -> "X", PlotRange -> All]
```

But I think that it is not correct since when trying to verify with the solid given by $y=1$ and $y=0$ (in this case, a cylinder should appear) but the graph appears empty.

How can I view the order? thank you.

Actualization: By example, with the command

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{x, 1}, {x, 2}}, {x, 0, 1}, RevolutionAxis -> "X"]
```

The revolution generated by each curve appears but I would like the volume between the two revolutions to come out with padding. (That is, I would like to visually see a solid cylinder.) Is there a command that can do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You neglected to define your functions so MM does not know what to do.

```
f[x_] := x
g[x_] := x^2
RevolutionPlot3D[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, RevolutionAxis -> "X", 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Thanks. A doubt: If RevolutionPlot3D[{{x, 1}, {x, 2}}, {x, 0, 10}, RevolutionAxis -> X] Is it possible to fill the volume?

Answer (score 2):

We can add a line `{c,x^2}, 0<=x<=c` for `c=1`.

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, x^2}, {1, x^2}}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{x, x^2}, {1, x^2}}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, RevolutionAxis -> "X", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The RevolutionPlot3D only plots the surface of revolution - it does not plot any interior points to create a filled object.  Suggest you look at the following posts using RegionPlot3D.

[Filling in a RevolutionPlot3D?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144989/filling-in-a-revolutionplot3d)

[Filling the empty space in RevolutionPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59056/filling-the-empty-space-in-revolutionplot3d/59066#59066)