# Revolution of a 2D graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, geometric-transform

I would like to know how can we make a revolution around an axis of a 2D shape (a rectangle for example).
I saw that there is the RevolutionPlot function but I can't manage to use it.
I would also like the result to be solid.
**How to do ?**

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283884/solid-of-revolution, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59056/filling-the-empty-space-in-revolutionplot3d, and perhaps https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144989/filling-in-a-revolutionplot3d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can rotate a convex polygon.

```
SeedRandom[111];
reg = RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 7}, DataRange -> {{2, 5}, {1, 4}}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[], reg}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

- We rotate all of the sides of the convex polygon around the direction `{0, 0, 1}`

```
pairs = MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@reg, 1][[;; , 
     1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {0, x, y};
ParametricPlot3D[
 RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}] /@ ({1 - t, t} . # & /@ 
     pairs) // Evaluate, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{π, 1.3 π}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], PlotPoints -> {60, 10}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.8], LightGreen], 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

- The example in the comment of the question.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] = 2 + Log[x];
g[x_] = 1;
reg = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 1, E}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics;
pairs = MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@reg, 1][[;; , 
     1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y, 0};
ParametricPlot3D[
 RotationTransform[θ, {1, 0, 0}] /@ ({1 - t, t} . # & /@ 
     pairs) // Evaluate, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{π, 1.3 π}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], PlotPoints -> {60, 10}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.8], LightGreen], 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

- But for any arbitrary graphics,for example,the text of font, it is still needs to find another way to deal with.